# Low complexity shader to indicate the sides of a polyline

Tags: glsl, opengl-es2

I have a bunch of polylines that I draw using GL_LINES. They can have thousands of points. They actually represent the separation of land and water on a map. I don't have complete polygons, just the ordered set of points.
[image]

I'm looking for a neat but efficient way to visually convey Side A and Side B as being different. For example I could offset the polyline in one direction a few times and fade it out (but every offset is doubling the number of points), or offset it once to make a "ribbon" and give one side a 'glow' like effect to mimic the outer glow or shadow of a polygon).

This is for a mobile application and I'm using OpenGL ES 2. I'd like to keep the effect as simple as possible from a complexity stand point. I'm looking for some additional ideas; maybe there's a clever shader technique out there or a visual effect I haven't considered.

Comment: How do you know which side is which? Are they always left side and right side? Are the polylines connected or disjoint?

Comment: The polylines are ordered such that 'left' is always SideA and 'right' is always SideB. The polylines aren't completely continuous, they're disjoint at places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of geometry shaders, you'll have to do something with your input data.

A simple approach would be to create a quad for each line segment, extending N pixels in the X axis. In old style GL immediate mode pseudo-code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
for each line {
    glColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glVertex(line.x0 - N, line.y0)
    glColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
    glVertex(line.x0, line.y0)
    glColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
    glVertex(line.x1, line.y1)
    glColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
    glVertex(line.x1 - N, line.y1)
}
```

If you want even prettier results: offset along a vector perpendicular to the line (instead of just in the X-axis) to get an even thickness, and fill in the gaps in the line joins. Look at 2d line art stroking algorithms (like in postscript) for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your suggestion is pretty much what I meant when I said 'offsetting' in my original question. I'm looking for more 'outside-the-box' ideas (if I don't get any, I'll select your answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not better than offsetting the coordinates to produce a texturable triangle strip, and I haven't tested it, but since you're looking for ideas:

Use a thick line width, and a fragment shader which draws a glow on one side by comparing the interpolated projected vertex coordinate (passed from the vertex shader) to `gl_FragCoord` and deriving a gradient from the difference. I don't know exactly how varyings are interpolated on thick lines, so I don't know how well this will actually work.

Note that wide lines may be inefficient or even not supported by your hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately (as you predicted) I couldn't really get wide lines working correctly. I appreciate the reply though; it was a good idea.